# How to receive an image in an Android application from raspberry pi via bluetooth and display it in an image view as jpg image

Tags: android, python, image, bluetooth

I want to capture an image by raspberry pi camera and send that image to my android app through Bluetooth RFCOMM channel connection ... I am send the image as bytes from python script , but I don't know how I can receive it in android as bytes and display it in an image view  ???

I am try receive a string and success in it, but I don't know how to receive an image in android app ???

this is my python script , Is there any suggestions in android side please??

```py
import os
import picamera
import lightblue 
import glob
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from bluetooth import *
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
camera=picamera.PiCamera()
prev_input=0
input1=GPIO.input(23)
input2=GPIO.input(25)
connection=False
server_sock=BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)
port=server_sock.getsockname()[1]
uuid="94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
advertise_service(server_sock,"BagPiServer",service_id=uuid,service_classes=[uuid,SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],profiles=[SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE])
while True:
      if(connection==False):
              print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" %port)
              client_sock,client_info=server_sock.accept()
              connection=True
              print("The Bag accepted connection from ",client_info)
              GPIO.output(24,1)
      try:
              data=client_sock.recv(1024)
              if(data=="disconnect"):
                    print("Client wanted to disconnect")
                    client_sock.close()
                    connection=False
              elif(data=="connect"):
                  msg="nothing"
                  time.sleep(5)
                  if((not prev_input) and input1):
                      msg="B"
                      image=camera.capture(stream,'a1.jpeg')
                      try:
                      myfile=open(image,'rb')
                      bytes=myfile.read()
                      client_sock.sendall(bytes)
                      finally:
                      connectiom.close()
                  else:
                      msg="F"
                  client_sock.send(msg)
                  time.sleep(5)
                  client_sock.close()
                  except IOError:
                  print("Connection disconnected")
                  GPIO.output(24,0)
                  client_sock.close()
                  connection=False
                  pass
                  except BluetoothError:
                  print("something want error with bluetooth")
                  except KeyboardInterrupt:
                  print("\nDisconnected")
                  client_sock.close()
                  server_sock.close()
                  break
```

Comment: Hi, you have to use Android's Bluetooth SDK which uses BluetoothSocket and Inputstream/Outputstreams to read / write bytes from/over a RFCOMM Bluetooth connection. This guide will help you understand how to use Bluetooth on Android: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat. Then you can use Bitmap class to decode a byte array and load it up in an ImageView :)

Comment: @Mackovich Thank you, I am try that but I don't have any result or error to solve. My Code : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tmkm59axL4ivh-a1orhj3Z5h-4WPTY9YiXdUxZYG94o

Comment: It is hard to help when we only have the python side and not the Android's side of the Bluetooth code.

Comment: I have the android side, but it isn't give a result or error, so I asked if there is any one try or success in that before to solve my android code or make suggestions to another ways@Mackovich